# How to query for an image in rich text

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I am attempting to query for an image in a rich text field in Contentful. What should my query look like? Here is my query:

```
query {allContentfulBlogPost (
sort: {
  fields: publishedDate,
  order: DESC
}){
edges {
  node {
    title
    slug
    publishedDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
    body {
      raw
      references {
        ... on ContentfulAsset {
          contentful_id
          fixed(width: 1600) {
            width
            height
            src
            srcSet
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

And this is the code in my editor. The image will not display.

```
const Blog = (props) => { const options = {
renderNode: {
  "embedded-asset-block": (node) => {
    const alt = node.data.target.fields.title["en-US"]
    const url = node.target.sys.id.references.fixed.src
    return <img alt={alt} src={url} />
  }
}
```

}
This is the raw data response from my query:

```
              "raw": "{\"nodeType\":\"document\",\"data\":{},\"content\":[{\"nodeType\":\"paragraph\",\"content\":[{\"nodeType\":\"text\",\"value\":\"Here is a recipe for chewy chocolate chip cookies.\",\"marks\":[],\"data\":{}}],\"data\":{}},{\"nodeType\":\"embedded-asset-block\",\"content\":[],\"data\":{\"target\":{\"sys\":{\"id\":\"3eIIsGhe0e1my0IRJtstRp\",\"type\":\"Link\",\"linkType\":\"Asset\"}}}},{\"nodeType\":\"paragraph\",\"content\":[{\"nodeType\":\"text\",\"value\":\"\",\"marks\":[],\"data\":{}}],\"data\":{}}]}",
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should look like:

```
query {
  allContentfulBlogPost {
    edges {
      node {
        bodyRichText {
          raw
          references {
            ... on ContentfulAsset {
              contentful_id
              fixed(width: 1600) {
                width
                height
                src
                srcSet
              }
            }
            ... on ContentfulBlogPost {
              contentful_id
              title
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the:

```
  fixed(width: 1600) {
    width
    height
    src
    srcSet
  }
```

*Note: additionally you can use one of the GraphQL fragments exposed like `...GatsbyContentfulFixed`. More details: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/*

If you are using `gatsby-image` you need a bunch of additional fields like the ones in the snippet above. If you are using a standard `<img>` tag, you just need the source (`src`) of the image.

At this point, you'll need to use something like:

```
import { BLOCKS, MARKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
​
const Bold = ({ children }) => <span className="bold">{children}</span>
const Text = ({ children }) => <p className="align-center">{children}</p>
​
const options = {
  renderMark: {
    [MARKS.BOLD]: text => <Bold>{text}</Bold>,
  },
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <Text>{children}</Text>,
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => {
      console.log("embedded asset",node)
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Asset</h2>
          <pre>
            <code>{JSON.stringify(node, null, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </>
      )
    },
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: node => {
      console.log("embedded entry",node)
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Embedded Entry</h2>
          {/* Using gatsby-image */}
          <Img fixed={node.target.sys.id.references.fixed}  />
          {/* Using img */}
          <img src={node.target.sys.id.references.fixed.src} />
        </>
      )
    },  
  },
}

renderRichText(node.bodyRichText, options)
```

I'm assuming that the nesting structure (`node.target.sys.id.references.fixed`) is correct, if not, try debugging, starting at `node` using the `console.logs` as support.

Useful resources:

- https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/

Comment: I am not using gatsby-image plugin. This code                                                               
              ... on ContentfulBlogPost {
              contentful_id
              title
              slug
            }
          }                                                                                                                        
 gives me this error                                                                                  
    Fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type \"ContentfulAsset\" can never be of type \"ContentfulBlogPost\"."

Comment: Use the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to define your final query, otherwise, it's impossible to guess your data structure. You should get the idea of the answer, which is to adapt this approach to your needs. Use the `src` of the image (applying a valid query) and add it in a `[BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]` node. Keep in mind that fragments are not valid in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` but they are valid to be used in a query.

Comment: Does `fixed` need any special plugin? It does not work for me: `Cannot query field "fixed" on type "ContentfulAsset"`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, I would just add `__typename`, so it would look like this:

```
      body {
        raw
        references {
          ... on ContentfulAsset {
            contentful_id
            fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
              ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp
            }
            __typename
          }
        }
      }
```

Then import the renderRichText function from gatsby-source-contentful, as well as BLOCKS from rich-text-types:

```
import { renderRichText } from "gatsby-source-contentful/rich-text"
import { BLOCKS } from "@contentful/rich-text-types"
```

Create your options object:

```
  const options = {
    renderNode: {
      [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: node => <Img {...node.data.target} />,
    },
  }
```

Finally, use the renderRichText function in your JSX like this (assuming you've desctructured `body` from your data:

```
<div className="container">
   {renderRichText(body, options)}
</div>
```

This comes from the example [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/25249), and it's working for me. Just keep in mind you need updated versions of the packages, especially source-contentful. Good luck :)